# KivyMd + Plyer: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: kivymd

I want to add notifications to my kivyMD app.

First I got this error:

> AttributeError: type object 'notification.org.notificator.R$drawable' has no attribute 'icon'.

So I changed my buildozer.spec requirements to include:

```
https://github.com/kivy/plyer/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
```

Now I get this error:

> JVM exception occurred: org.test.xon: Targeting
> S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of
> FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be
> specified when creating a PendingIntent.
> Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only
> use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends
> on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs
> to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

In google colab...

> sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-17-jdk python3-pip autoconf
> libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
> libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev
>
> pip3 install --upgrade Cython==0.29.19
>
> pip3 install --upgrade buildozer
>
> buildozer init

buildozer.spec:

> android.api = 33
>
> requirements =
> python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.0.2,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow,requests,schedule,urllib3,charset_normalizer,idna,kaki,kivy_garden.graph,https://github.com/kivy/plyer/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

Thank you

Comment: The second one is not an error.  *Strongly consider* is a suggestion. It's offering a suggestion that it thinks you should think about doing. It's telling you that you should consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE unless you have a specific reason for using FLAG_MUTABLE. Did you read the words in that suggestion? I don't see any mention of an *error* or *warning*.