# FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG MUTABLE in notification kivy for android

Tags: python, android, kivy

I have a simple code that show a notification using the plyer.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.utils import platform
from plyer import notification
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import DictProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Builder.load_string(""" 
<NotificationDemo>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: notification_text
            text: 'Hi user'
            font_size:50
         
""")
a=0
class NotificationDemo(BoxLayout):
    kwargs = DictProperty()
    def update(self,dt):
        global a
        try:
            a = a + 1
            sms = str(a)
            self.ids.notification_text.text = sms
            notification.notify(title='hello' , message=sms)
        except Exception as error:
            self.ids.notification_text.text = str(error)

class ServiceApp(App):
    def build(self):
        fdir = NotificationDemo()
        Clock.schedule_interval(fdir.update, 6)
        return fdir
        
    def on_pause(self):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ServiceApp().run()
```

This code work correctly on Windows and low Androids. But when I run this code on Android 13 I get the following error.

> JVM exception occurred : org.test.notify : Targeting S + ( version 31 and above ) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG MUTABLE be specified when creating a Pendingintent . Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE , only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the Pendingintent being mutable , e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles . java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

I have seen similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75246582/android-app-crashes-when-i-want-to-send-a-notificationkivy-python-plyer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74008508/kivymd-plyer-targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-im) but they have no answers.
Should I use the service? Or should I do something in the buildozer.spec?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: There is a matching open issue in the plyer repo https://github.com/kivy/plyer/issues/702

Comment: Thanks. There is no answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

I havent been able to get a solution and it doesnt appear to be on any ones care list.

My solution in the end was to use the pushyy module (google pushyy by fox520 for kivy) in conjunction with firebases cloud messaging, which in the end is a good solution because it has added bonuses, and its free cloud messaging.

Another option that I havent tried is, I see kvdroid  package also does notifications and may work with api above 31, not certain but worth looking into if ya stuck

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I will try to check them.